Showing django static images on emails
I am trying to send an email with django static images on my emails like using {% static "path_to_img" %}, but that's not working. Then I tried giving the image it's full path by giving the url and the domain in my view, but that's not working either.
My mail.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
<head>
    <title>Order Placed - Pending Approval</title>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 20px; color: #333; background-color: #f5f5f5;">
    <div style="background-color: white; padding: 20px; border: 1px solid #ddd;">
        <header style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
            <img src="{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}{% static 'event/images/logo.svg' %}" alt="" style="height: 30px;">
        </header>

        <div style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 20px;">
            <img src="{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}{% static 'event/images/order_received.png' %}" alt="Order Status" style="width: 80%; max-width: 400px;">
        </div>
        
        <h1 style="font-size: 24px; margin-bottom: 5px;">Thanks for your order!</h1>
        <p style="margin-bottom: 20px;">Order number: #{{ order.ref_code }}</p>
        
        <p style="margin-bottom: 20px;">Hi {{ order.user.first_name }},<br>
        Your order has been sent to the vendor(s) to confirm. You will receive another email very soon confirming your booking. If you have any questions, please email us at or you can message the vendor(s) directly via your dashboard.</p>
        
        <a href="#" style="display: block; background-color: #8B0000; color: white; text-align: center; padding: 10px; text-decoration: none; margin-bottom: 20px;">Log into account</a>
        
        <div style="background-color: #333; color: white; padding: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <h2 style="margin: 0; font-size: 18px;">Order Information</h2>
        </div>
        
        <table style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; margin-bottom: 20px; background-color: white;">
            <tbody>
                {% for item in cart_items %}
                <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;">
                    <td style="padding: 10px;">
                        <img src="{{ item.image }}" alt="{{ item.name }}" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; object-fit: cover;">
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding: 10px;">
                        <strong>{{ item.name }}</strong>
                        {% if item.hire %} (Hire){% endif %}<br>
                        {% if item.hire %}
                            {{ item.hire_duration|title }}s: {{ item.quantity }}
                        {% else %}
                            Quantity: {{ item.quantity }}
                        {% endif %}
                        {% for variation in item.variations %}
                            <br>{{ variation.variation_name }}: {{ variation.variation_value }}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: right;">${{ item.item_total_price }}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="padding: 10px; text-align: right;"><strong>Subtotal:</strong></td>
                    <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: right;">${{ subtotal|floatformat:2 }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="padding: 10px; text-align: right;"><strong>Delivery:</strong></td>
                    <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: right;">${{ delivery_fee|floatformat:2 }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="padding: 10px; text-align: right;"><strong>Setup/Packdown Fee:</strong></td>
                    <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: right;">${{ setup_packdown_fee|floatformat:2 }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="padding: 10px; text-align: right;"><strong>Total:</strong></td>
                    <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: right;"><strong>${{ total_price|floatformat:2 }}</strong></td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
        
        <div style="background-color: #333; color: white; padding: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <h2 style="margin: 0; font-size: 18px;">Customer Information</h2>
        </div>
        
        <div style="background-color: white; padding: 10px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
            <h3 style="margin-bottom: 5px;">Customer details</h3>
            <p style="margin: 0;">{{ order.user.name }}<br>
            {{ order.user.email }}<br>
            {{ order.user.phone }}</p>
            
            <h3 style="margin: 15px 0 5px;">Event details</h3>
            <p style="margin: 0;">
                Date: {{ order.event_date }}<br>
                Time: {{ order.event_time|time:"h:i A" }}<br>
                Address: {{ order.address }}, {{ order.city }}, {{ order.state }}, {{ order.postal_code }}
            </p>

            
            <h3 style="margin: 15px 0 5px;">Delivery/pickup method</h3>
            <p style="margin: 0;">
                {% for item in cart_items %}
                    {% if item.delivery_method == 'delivery' %}
                        Delivery to {{ order.address }}, {{ order.city }}, {{ order.state }}, {{ order.postal_code }} for {{ item.name }}<br>
                    {% else %}
                        Pickup at {{ item.pickup_location }} for {{ item.name }}<br>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </p>

            <h3 style="margin: 15px 0 5px;">Payment method</h3>
            <p style="margin: 0;">
                {% if order.payment_method == 'afterpay_clearpay' %}
                    Afterpay
                {% else %}
                    Card
                {% endif %}
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <p style="text-align: center; margin: 20px 0;">Got a question? Email us at </p>
    
    <p style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 10px;">DON'T FORGET TO FOLLOW US</p>
    
    <div style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <!-- Social media links can be added here -->
    </div>
    
    <div style="text-align: center; font-size: 12px;">
        <a href="{% url 'privacy_policy' %}" style="color: #333; text-decoration: none; margin: 0 10px;">PRIVACY POLICY</a>
        <a href="{% url 'home' %}" style="color: #333; text-decoration: none; margin: 0 10px;">VISIT US</a>
        <a href="{% url 'terms_and_conditions' %}" style="color: #333; text-decoration: none; margin: 0 10px;">TERMS OF USE</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Neither the header image, the next image or the product images are working. I honestly don't know what to do.
My rendered html page source:
<title>Order Placed - Pending Approval</title>
</head>
<div>
    <div style="background-color:white;padding:20px;border:1px solid #ddd;">
        
            <img alt="" style="min-height:30px;">
        

        <div style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:20px;">
            <img alt="Order Status" style="width:80%;max-width:400px;">
        </div>
        
        <h1 style="font-size:24px;margin-bottom:5px;">Thanks for your order!</h1>
        <p style="margin-bottom:20px;">Order number: #c9jFZ2Dxoj</p>
        
        <p style="margin-bottom:20px;">Hi Joe,<br>
        Your order has been sent to the vendor(s) to confirm. You will receive another email very soon confirming your booking. If you have any questions, please email us at or you can message the vendor(s) directly via your dashboard.</p>
        
        <a rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" style="display:block;background-color:#8B0000;color:white;text-align:center;padding:10px;text-decoration:none;margin-bottom:20px;">Log into account</a>
        
        <div style="background-color:#333;color:white;padding:10px;margin-bottom:10px;">
            <h2 style="margin:0;font-size:18px;">Order Information</h2>
        </div>
        
        <table style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;margin-bottom:20px;background-color:white;">
            <tbody>
                
                <tr style="border-bottom:1px solid #eee;">
                    <td style="padding:10px;">
                        <img alt="Custom DJ Package" style="width:50px;min-height:50px;">
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding:10px;">
                        <strong>Custom DJ Package</strong>
                        <br>
                        
                            Quantity: 1
                        
                        
                            <br>DJ packages: Corporate Event
                        
                            <br>Size: Medium
                        
                            <br>Color: Green
                        
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding:10px;text-align:right;">$996.0</td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr style="border-bottom:1px solid #eee;">
                    <td style="padding:10px;">
                        <img alt="Bridal Mannequins" style="width:50px;min-height:50px;">
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding:10px;">
                        <strong>Bridal Mannequins</strong>
                         (Hire)<br>
                        
                            Days: 2
                        
                        
                            <br>Mannequin: Groom Mannequin
                        
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding:10px;text-align:right;">$240.0</td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr style="border-bottom:1px solid #eee;">
                    <td style="padding:10px;">
                        <img alt="Bridal Mannequins" style="width:50px;min-height:50px;">
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding:10px;">
                        <strong>Bridal Mannequins</strong>
                        <br>
                        
                            Quantity: 1
                        
                        
                            <br>Mannequin: Both
                        
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding:10px;text-align:right;">$350.0</td>
                </tr>
                
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="padding:10px;text-align:right;"><strong>Subtotal:</strong></td>
                    <td style="padding:10px;text-align:right;">$1586.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="padding:10px;text-align:right;"><strong>Delivery:</strong></td>
                    <td style="padding:10px;text-align:right;">$140.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="padding:10px;text-align:right;"><strong>Setup/Packdown Fee:</strong></td>
                    <td style="padding:10px;text-align:right;">$0.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="padding:10px;text-align:right;"><strong>Total:</strong></td>
                    <td style="padding:10px;text-align:right;"><strong>$1726.00</strong></td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
        
        <div style="background-color:#333;color:white;padding:10px;margin-bottom:10px;">
            <h2 style="margin:0;font-size:18px;">Customer Information</h2>
        </div>
        
        <div style="background-color:white;padding:10px;margin-bottom:20px;">
            <h3 style="margin-bottom:5px;">Customer details</h3>
            <p style="margin:0;"><br>
            abrarshahriar360@yahoo.com<br>
            </p>
            
            <h3 style="margin:15px 0 5px;">Event details</h3>
            <p style="margin:0;">
                Date: 2024-08-16<br>
                Time: 10:45 AM<br>
                Address: 128 Walters Road, Blacktown NSW, Australia, Adelaide, SA, 5000
            </p>

            
            <h3 style="margin:15px 0 5px;">Delivery/pickup method</h3>
            <p style="margin:0;">
                
                    
                        Delivery to 128 Walters Road, Blacktown NSW, Australia, Adelaide, SA, 5000 for Custom DJ Package<br>
                    
                
                    
                        Delivery to 128 Walters Road, Blacktown NSW, Australia, Adelaide, SA, 5000 for Bridal Mannequins<br>
                    
                
                    
                        Pickup at Dernancourt for Bridal Mannequins<br>
                    
                
            </p>

            <h3 style="margin:15px 0 5px;">Payment method</h3>
            <p style="margin:0;">
                
                    Card
                
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <p style="text-align:center;margin:20px 0;">Got a question? Email us at </p>
    
    <p style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;margin-bottom:10px;">DON&#39;T FORGET TO FOLLOW US</p>
    
    <div style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:20px;">
        
    </div>
    
    <div style="text-align:center;font-size:12px;">
        <a rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" style="color:#333;text-decoration:none;margin:0 10px;">PRIVACY POLICY</a>
        <a rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" style="color:#333;text-decoration:none;margin:0 10px;">VISIT US</a>
        <a rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" style="color:#333;text-decoration:none;margin:0 10px;">TERMS OF USE</a>
    </div>
</div>
</html>


need rendered email html

I have added rendered html page source, thanks

Is this the result rendered by Django? Or is it the html of the email you received?

Email I received from running the code, how do I get the result rendered by django?

It's not only images, but links such as privacy policy and others are also not working.

Where do you use email?
I guess it's filtered out by email itself.

Give it a try without "request.build_absolute_uri" and test it with a hardcoded base url at least. In my emails my images happen to be public anyway, and the url to go to is just a variable, and I find this works for me.
Generally if the image is private, if you're using something like AWS with an S3 bucket, you can generate a signed url with a bit of python. Other services should have equivalents.
